# If I need to pull json data from a web page then that web page must have some json kind of data or we can pull jason data from any kind of web page?

Tags: python, json

I wrote below code as a practice on json files, and I am not able to pull out json data from the web page please correct the code and help me with, what kind of web pages are suitable for pulling out a json file or can we pull json from any kind of web pages

```
 import urllib.request
 url="https://x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1"
 source_file=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 page=source_file.read()
 data=json.loads(page)
 print(data)
```

Comment: Yes, of course the page must return a valid JSON string for you to be able to decode it as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of web apis returns data in json.
if you are trying to scrape a website then you have to parse html or xml using any parser.